# How can you override the activerecord has_many assoication build method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I would like to override the build method of a has_many assoication.

```
class OtherThings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_model
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :other_things
end
```

such that

```
m = MyModel.create
m.other_things.build  # i'd like to add additional logic within the build method...
```

I have gone about by updating the new method of OtherThings, but that is getting a little messy. I'd like my logic to only happen when being associated hence the build...

Answer (score 0):

Im unsure of what your trying to do with build. if your trying to just add more methods just attach .whatever_method to the end. Also, the models will always be associated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by using around_create.